# php slim 405 method not allowed

Tags: php, oracle, microservices, slim

I'm a newb with php slim framework and am struggling with the below:

I have tried `-->post` and `-->patch` both returning **405 method not allowed: POST (or PATCH, if it is patch)**

```
$app->post('/export', function ($request, $response, $args) {    // tried post and patch here

    $which = $_POST['table'];
  
    $db = $this->db;
    $repo = new dataRepo($this->db);

    if ($which == 'Table 1'){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM app.table_1';

    } else if ($which == 'Table 2'){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM app.table_2';

    } else if ($which == 'Table 3'){
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM app.table_3';

    }

    $stmt = oci_parse($this->db, $sql);

    while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt, OCI_ASSOC)) != false) {
        echo "<tr>";
        
        foreach ($row as $columnName => $columnValue){
            echo "<td>".$columnValue."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    $file = fopen($type + ".csv","w");

    if (!@oci_execute($stmt)) {
        $error = oci_error($stmt);
        throw new Exception($error['message']);
    }
});
```

Below is the front-end ajax call.. what am I doing wrong here?

```
  $('#export' + '.' + crnt).click(function(){
        let which = crnt; // console.logs as 'Table 1' or 'Table 2 or 3'
        $.ajax({
          url: "/export", 
          data: { table:which },
          success: function(data){
          console.log('success ninja');

        }});
      });
```

Comment: `$app->post('/export', ...)` means `/export` will respond to **POST** requests only. This means the ajax call should make a post request. This can be done by adding `method: 'post'` to options.

Comment: Thanks so I updated with specified method as post: and am now getting a 500 error. i.e.  $.ajax({
          url: "/export", 
          data: { table:which },
          method: 'post',
          success: function(data){
          console.log('success ninja' + data);

        }});

Comment: That is probably caused by an exception in the route callback.